# JQuery from CDN - what's covered?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, cdn

I feel like an utter noob for having to ask this particular question, but I've gotten to the point where my lack of understanding is causing problems.

I'm using Google's CDN to provide JQuery and JQuery-UI. I've also got JQuery Tools coming from their own CDN.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```

Then there are a bunch of specific scripts, such as:

```
ui/jquery.ui.core.js
ui/jquery.ui.tabs
ui/jquery.ui.widget.js
ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js
ui/jquery.ui.slider.js
jquery.ui.stars.min
ui/jquery.effects.core
ui/jquery.effects.highlight
ui/jquery.effects.core.js
ui/jquery.effects.blind.js
```

In the past, whenever I've removed some of these, things seem to stop working, but I'm tired of the ridiculous number of scripts on some of my pages so I want to sort this out. Which of these is covered by the minimized CDN file? Are these extras actually needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDN file includes all packages.

To determine the minimum packages required, you can go to the [jQuery UI Custom downloader page](http://jqueryui.com/download), deselect all components, and then just tick the ones you need. Internal dependencies are automatically added to the list. If it turns out that your list of components that you need isn't particularly large, then maybe you'd be better off building your own custom package.